# How to get the coordinates of a datum point created using "DatumPointByEdgeParam" in Abaqus using Python scripts?

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to create vertices on the edge of a solid model to apply loads. I started by creating datum points at the required locations along the edge, with the idea of using those points to partition the edge and apply loads on the resulting vertices:

```py
sample_point = plateAssembly.DatumPointByEdgeParam(
    edge=loading_edge, parameter=fraction_of_length
)
```

This is creating an entity that is visible in the GUI, but not as a vertex.

This was probably not the correct way to do that, since I am unable to get the coordinates of the created point (or rather do anything else with it), since the resulting feature object saved to `sample_point` does not directly provide coordinates and is instead defined in relation to the edge that it was created from:

```py
>>> print sample_point`

({'children': '', 'edgeParameter': 0.1, 'id': 8, 'isOutOfDate': False, 'name': 'Datum pt-4', 'parents': '2&', 'path': 'unknown', 'sketch': 'unknown'})`
```

This feels like it is something very basic, but I haven't managed to find anything about what I should do differently anywhere that I looked. I am an absolute beginner, so I am not sure if I am even looking in the right places to begin with.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but there's a `getByBoundingSphere` (or box, or cylinder) command that makes it fairly easy to grab points via their co-ordinates and assign them to sets

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat, for that you have to know the coordinates, which OP is trying to find in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `DatumPointByEdgeParam` [documentation](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch20pyo01.html#ker-feature-datumpointbyedgeparam-pyc):

> This method creates a Feature object and a DatumPoint object along an
> edge at a selected distance from one end of the edge.
>
> <...>
>
> **Return value**
>
> A Feature object.

So, as you said the variable `sample_point` is not referencing the [`DatumPoint`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch15pyo05.html) object but the [`Feature object`](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm?startat=pt01ch20pyo01.html)

To get the `DatumPoint` object associated with the feature `sample_point` you can simply use its `id`:

```py
sample_point_dp = plateAssembly.datums[sample_point.id]
```